# Why am i getting a bigger list of search results than those on the webpage i am scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to collect all href links of the houses listed for sale but when i run my program i get a list of about 50 though this is far higher than the number of houses listed / href links on this single page (`url`).

I have tried looking at the source code of the page and cross referencing the results from my program, and though some are a match there's some which can not be found on the  web site page (`url`).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url='https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?searchType=SALE&locationIdentifier=REGION%5E1091&insId=1&radius=0.0&minPrice=&maxPrice=&minBedrooms=&maxBedrooms=&displayPropertyType=&maxDaysSinceAdded=&_includeSSTC=on&sortByPriceDescending=&primaryDisplayPropertyType=&secondaryDisplayPropertyType=&oldDisplayPropertyType=&oldPrimaryDisplayPropertyType=&newHome=&auction=false'

Web_Page = requests.get(url)
Soup = bs(Web_Page.text,'html.parser')
Web_Section_Of_Interest= Soup.find_all('a',class_="propertyCard-link")


count=0
for item in Web_Section_Of_Interest:
    print('https://www.rightmove.co.uk'+item.get('href'))
    count+=1

print(count)
```

I am getting a list of 50 href links

But i was expecting a list that matched the number of houses listed on the `url` web page which would be 25.

Comment: The website has two links with class `propertyCard-link` per property card. You either want only every second element or you filter for all `<a>` elements that are direct descendents of `<div class="propertyCard-details">`

Comment: replacing the class from `"propertyCard-link"` to `"propertyCard-img-link"` worked. I posted the whole code below as an answer. Good luck!

Comment: I see 23 non featured property listings, 1 featured and 1 land for sale. Would you expect to retrieve all  those?

Comment: @QHarr yes i would want to retrieve all of those too, though from what was mentioned above i see the flaw in my logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the actual url that you're printing, you'd notice it's printing duplicates. So technically you are only getting 25.

```
print(count)
https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/property-61358637.html
https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/property-61358637.html
https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/property-57044346.html
https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/property-57044346.html
https://www.rightmove.co.uk/commercial-property-for-sale/property-70211329.html
https://www.rightmove.co.uk/commercial-property-for-sale/property-70211329.html
https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/property-68319664.html
https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/property-68319664.html
....
```

Just looking at the first 2 elements in your propertyCard-link elements. One is a 'summary', and the other is a 'details':

```
Web_Section_Of_Interest[0]
Out[6]: 
<a class="propertyCard-link" data-bind="click: propertyCardClick('details'), attr: { href: computedDetailsLink() }" data-test="property-details" href="/property-for-sale/property-61358637.html">
<h2 class="propertyCard-title" data-bind="text: propertyTypeFullDescription" itemprop="name">
            2 bedroom semi-detached house for sale        </h2>
<address class="propertyCard-address" itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<meta content="Auckland Road, Potters Bar" data-bind="attr: { content: displayAddress }" itemprop="streetAddress"/>
<meta content="GB" data-bind="attr: { content: countryCode }" itemprop="addressCountry"/>
<span data-bind="text: displayAddress">Auckland Road, Potters Bar</span>
</address>
</a>

Web_Section_Of_Interest[1]
Out[7]: 
<a class="propertyCard-link" data-bind="click: propertyCardClick('summary'), attr: { href: computedDetailsLink() }" href="/property-for-sale/property-61358637.html">
<span data-bind="html: summary" data-test="property-description" itemprop="description">BPM Auckland are pleased to offer this spacious Extended 2 Double bedroom 1930's built semi detached house, situated in this popular location within easy reach of good schools including Dame Alice Owens. The property benefits from a large 190' rear garden and also potential for a loft conversion...</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the issue by replacing the class from `"propertyCard-link"` to `"propertyCard-img-link"`

**Working Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url='https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?searchType=SALE&locationIdentifier=REGION%5E1091&insId=1&radius=0.0&minPrice=&maxPrice=&minBedrooms=&maxBedrooms=&displayPropertyType=&maxDaysSinceAdded=&_includeSSTC=on&sortByPriceDescending=&primaryDisplayPropertyType=&secondaryDisplayPropertyType=&oldDisplayPropertyType=&oldPrimaryDisplayPropertyType=&newHome=&auction=false'

Web_Page = requests.get(url)
Soup = bs(Web_Page.text,'html.parser')
Web_Section_Of_Interest= Soup.find_all('a',class_="propertyCard-img-link")

count=0

for item in Web_Section_Of_Interest:
    print('https://www.rightmove.co.uk'+item.get('href'))
    count+=1

print(count)
```